# Install Glassfish Eclipse Plugin without internet conenction?

Tags: eclipse, plugins, glassfish

I can't connect **Eclipse** to internet because of security issues in my work, i want to find a way to download the **Glassfish Eclipse Plugin** manually (Without using the **Eclipse Market Place** or **Eclipse Install Wizard**) and install it separately ...

I made many searches and all i found is how to install the Glassfish Eclipse Plugin using the download Link from **Eclipse Plugin Installer** ...
PS : **Glassfish Server** is already installed in my Laptop i just need the **Eclipse Plugin**.

From where can i download the Plugin ?

And how can i install it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GlassFish Tools is part of Oracle Enterprise Pack for Eclipse, which is offered in a number of different download formats, such as a ready-to-run Eclipse install and a downloadable repository. Either of these options is a good choice for users with connection problems. If you already have Eclipse installed, download the offline repository (may be called 'OEPE plugins only' on the download site). Then use the install plugins wizard, but point at the downloaded zip instead of a public URL. Make sure to uncheck the consult other repositories option to keep Eclipse from wandering to the network unnecessary.

[OEPE - Main Download Page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/eclipse/downloads/index.html)

[OEPE - Latest Release](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/eclipse/downloads/oepe-12111-1560492.html)